# Net6 equivalent of System.Runtime.Remoting.Lifetime?

Tags: .net-6.0

I'm trying to migrate a .Net4.8 application to .Net 6. The application uses the LifetimeServices class in System.Runtime.Remoting.Lifetime to specifically manage some object  lifetimes.

Does anyone know the equivalent .Net 6 namespace/nuget package for this or an equivalent set of operations?

Regards